# Modal math font commands in modern LaTeX? (i.e. modal version of \mathrm etc.)

Tags: math-mode, fonts, boldmath, portability, mathrm

Is there a modern *modal* version of the math font commands?

In modern LaTeX, the use of old font-commands like `\rm` is quite strongly discouraged, with the commands being removed from the Kernel, and therefore unavailable in modern versions of some document classes (the KOMA-script classes in particular).

However, I always found them quite useful to make editing easier, as I find reading and writing

```
\int_{\rm BZ} \chi^{\rm(2D)}
```

much easier than

```
\int_{\mathrm{BZ}} \chi^{\mathrm{(2D)}}
```

primarily due to the smaller level of brace-nesting.

In text-mode, there are modal commands like `\bfseries`¹, but these commands are forbidden in math-mode.

It is easy enough to reenable the font commands if needed (e.g. for compiling an old document) with `\DeclareOldFontCommand`, but is there some modern replacement?

**Note:** I am primarily looking for comands that are supported without custom definitions or special packages, as

- Journals may require that submitted documents use no packages beyond the template, and don't include user-defined macros.
- Custom commands make copy/paste of text and equations across documents difficult.

---

¹ Leaving other issues with using the modal commands asigde, in text-mode unlike math-mode, the word meant to be emphasized is rarely *already* in braces, so `Hello {\bfseries World}` provides no real advantage over `Hello \textbf{World}`, in the manner `a^{\rm stuff}` does compared to `a^{\rm stuff}` in math-mode.

Comment: There is nothing in the kernel so you will have to add a custom definition. I don't see any reason why you shouldn't use \DeclareOldFontCommand if your class doesn't provide them (btw: they are still in the KOMA classes only hidden).